# Authentication Providers, design pattern to adopt

Tags: authentication, design-patterns, win-universal-app

I have a windows phone 8.1 client.  This client connects to a Web API (ASP.NET) and fetches the supported Authentication Providers.  At the moment its Google and Twitter.  The user (wp 8.1) can select which provider he wants to use for the authentication purpose.

Based on the provider selected on the phone the underlying implementation flow for the authentication is different, in other words Google has one flow and Twitter has another flow.  Because of this I have switch statements in my client that looks like the following

```
switch(authProvider)
case: "Google":
  GoogleAuthProvider.PerfomAuthentication();
  break;
case: "Twitter"
  TwitterAuthProvider.PerformAuthentication();
  break;
```

My main problem around this is that I am now hard coding the provider.  The rest of my phone app uses IOC (MVVMLight) and in t this case I am hard coding.  How do I get rid of this, without explicitly referring to the container?  Plus lets say at a later point in time an additional auth provider is supported, then based on the current implementation I need to modify the client code as well, how do I minimize this?

Answer (score 0):

From the example you provided the State GoF pattern will be up to the task assuming that the authentication interface is uniform (consists of one method – `PerformAuthentication` and potentially of other methods that are common across all the other possible providers). So that you have to create the interface `IAuthenticationProvider` and inject its implementation into the logic that actually gets executed (the logic that previously contained `switch`).

In fact it is very similar to the Strategy that is injected via DI but Strategy just encapsulates the algorithm where State is more powerful and suitable for the domain of authentication (it might have …state and other methods/properties – not that bad, right? :)

If you face the providers with different functional capabilities and interfaces you might want to choose the Bridge pattern that unites the heterogeneous authentication interfaces under the umbrella of a single interface. But it seems to me that the usage of Bridge would be an overengineering here.